# Prohibiting passing certain values for method parameters

Tags: java, parameters

I have a method like this:

```
void method(int number){some code}
```

and i will call it like this:

```
method(-1)
```

is there a way in java to only allow passing positive integers to number parameter other than checking in the method body or making a checked exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring a checked exception doesn't make method parameters automatically validated somehow, it just means that the caller is obligated to check whether it was thrown, even if the code calls a literal `method(1)`.

If your application is complex enough, you can use Bean Validation and put a constraint on the method parameter:

```
void method(@Min(1) int number) { }
```

This is only worthwhile if you're already using a system complex enough to provide support for it, such as Spring or CDI. Otherwise, just stick to checking in the method body and throwing `IllegalArgumentException` if the requirements fail. Guava's `Preconditions` utility can be helpful here.

(Additionally, your code will be much easier to read if you follow the universal Java code standards. Type names start with capitals, but member and parameters names start with lowercase.)

Comment: A checked exception would force the method user to do a try and catch around it, So he would know it's invalid and still avoid throwing an exception at runtime. (Thanks for the tip, I started learning java from Processing which changes type names to lowercase. And when this problem occured i was using Processing (for its "Draw" method that is called n times per second where 0>n>1201) so it's a bit of a habit)

Comment: @OmarAbdul'Azeez But that's exactly the case where the user should just use `if` to check first. Best practice is to use exceptions for unusual circumstances and not ordinary flow control.

Comment: Well, The method user isn't the same as the coder so he wouldn't know it only accepts positive values unless there is something like this: 
[Image](https://prnt.sc/lgj0mv)

Comment: @OmarAbdul'Azeez That's why you should include Javadoc on all of your API that anyone else can see.